# How to run an asp dot net core image in Linux?

Tags: linux, docker, .net-core

I am using this docker file to build it

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk-alpine3.7 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY Packt.HelloWorld.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /published
RUN ls -alrth /published

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime-deps-alpine3.7 AS base
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /published .
RUN ls -alrth /app

# ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestApp.dll"] <-- I can run in Windows like this
ENTRYPOINT ["Packt.HelloWorld"]
```

The debug `ls` can show all files under the `/app` folder 
But if I use this

`ENTRYPOINT ["/app/Packt.HelloWorld"]`

It complained there is no such a path.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:348: starting container process ca                                                             
used "exec: \"/app/Packt.HelloWorld\": stat /app/Packt.HelloWorld: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

if I use

```
ENTRYPOINT ["Packt.HelloWorld"]
```

It gave me

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: 
container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: 
\"Packt.HelloWorld\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

The image seems to build properly and content are also in there, it's just the running not successful.

Can anyone give me a hint what I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the runtime of the publish subcommand of dotnet-cli. Also, the publishing process must create a self-contained application. Check the  [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21) for more information.

Comment: ah, thanks! I now update the publish command to `RUN dotnet publish --self-contained -r linuxmint.18.3-x64 -c Release -o /published`, but when I run it, it still give `standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"` if I have `/app`, and the same error if I don't have `/app`

Comment: I cannot see the `linuxmint.18.3-x64` runtime identifier at the page below. Setting it to `linux-x64` probably going to solve your issue. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog#linux-rids

Comment: AFAIK, you should try and keep things consistent. If you are using FDD on Windows, you should use FDD on linux as well (no `-r` with `publish`)

Comment: hmm, I am using ubuntu, `linuxmint.18.3-x64` is on the list. But I will try the `linux-x64`

Comment: ah, I actually have to use `alpine.3.7-x64`, now it finally works.

Answer (score 1):

```
# ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestApp.dll"] <-- I can run in Windows like this
```

This is pretty much exactly how it should work on Linux as well.

It looks like you are doing Framework Dependent Deployment (no `-r` or `--runtime` argument for `dotnet publish`). So the same steps to build/run on Windows should work on Linux as well.

Comment: actually, my linux box was not having the framework. I tried building it in my windows box with FDD, and I was not aware I should use self-contained for Linux. All good, thanks!

Comment: I think you are mixing things up. In your dockerfile, you are building the code inside the container, as FDD. You don't need to build self-contained on Linux. FDD works just fine. All of .NET Core tooling should work the same on Windows, Linux and macOS.

Comment: you are right, I was mixing things up, because I built the app in Windows in a different way, but I built for Linux in another way.